# SWT: Drag-and-drop Internal Object

Tags: java, swt, drag-and-drop

My application has a canvas and a table, I need to add drag-and-drop capabilities to it.  However, I read in a tutorial that Transfer converts the data I want to move into a platform-independent type.  I have no need to drag anything outside of my program, and it's important that the exact object be sent.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.  Apparently you can use some bogus transfer object, and keep the objects you want to move in your own variable.  Define the variable when the drag starts, (from the `DragSource`), and get the item from the variable in `DropTarget`.  Just ignore the bogus transfer object.

Comment: what TransferType did you use? do you mind providing some Code?

Comment: I don't remember, it was a while ago.  Just use the smallest one provided, and simply ignore it on the other end.

Comment: Example code, using a `LocalSelectionTransfer` http://georgiangrec.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/swt-composite-drag-and-drop/